# Docker+PM2 - NodeJS version is wrong during build

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, pm2

Inherited a project that has three main projects that, when deployed, all live on the same server:

1) API

2) Web

3) API-Worker

Problem is that I'm trying to update to newer versions of everything. I did so for API, but it killed the Web application, and I rolled it back. Turns-out that all through testing, separate servers are used, but when deployed, they live on the same production server.

Therefore, I want to sync the API and Web projects to the same node, npm, etc. versions. But, I'm getting some odd info during builds, so therefore the question.

To start - here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.20.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y graphicsmagick

RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install gulp -g
RUN npm install bower -g
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "pm2-docker", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

( side-question - is pm2-docker now replaced with pm2-runtime? )

Here's the ecosystem.config.js #1:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [

        {
            name: "API",
            script: "bin/www",
            instances: 1,
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            watch: false
        },
        {
            name: "API-Worker",
            script: "bin/worker",
            instances: 1,
            exec_mode: "cluster",
            watch: false
        },
    ],

    deploy: {
        production: {
            user: "root",
            host: [ "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ],
            ref: "origin/master",
            repo: "https://github.com/mycompany/etc",
            path: "/var/www/api",
            "post-deploy": "npm install && gulp sass && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production"
        }
    }
};
```

Here's ecosystem.config.js #2:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [

    {
      name: "Web",
      script: "bin/www",
      instances: 2,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      watch: "true"
    },
  ],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : "root",
      host : ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"],
      ref  : "origin/master",
      repo : "git@github.com:mycompany/etc",
      path : "/var/www/web",
      "post-deploy" : "npm install && npm run build:prod && pm2 startOrRestart ecosystem.config.js --env production"
    }
  }
};
```

The relevant part of the package.json files:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.20.1",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  },
```

BUT, when watching the build log I see this:

```
api_1    | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
api_1    | npm info using npm@3.10.10
api_1    | npm info using node@v6.9.5

...

web_1  | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
web_1    | npm info using npm@3.10.10
web_1    | npm info using node@v6.9.5
```

Going to the command-line in the docker directories locally, node -v says 10.20.1

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jolly

Comment: Did you find the answer to your side-question yet?

Comment: Kind-of...situation is that you need to fully-destroy existing docker containers, ensure that the Dockerfile uses the version of node you want, then do a docker-compose build --no-cache...At that point, I get a "wrong version of gulp-node-sass thing, I spawn another CL to build the node-sass using the same version of node. I finally migrated from MacOS to Windows 10. Next I'll upgrade node for the API layer to node 10 or 12 ( currently on 8.10 ). Then on the front-end, I'll build a front-end using Angular 7+ on node 10 or 12. The node development environment is real mess, in my opinion.